# How do I reset all of the form fields in a view when I refresh the page in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

How to reset all the fields in the form on each refresh in [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP)?

Comment: You should provide a code example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Are you asking how to make Cake not put data into the forms automatically, when using the form helper inside a view?  If so, Cake just takes the data inside Controller::$data and uses matching array indeces to field names to populate those fields.  To stop this, just set $this->data = null; in your controller's action that corresponds to the view.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can make all form data unreachable by setting $this-data to null.
You can also view the HTML page generated, what names the form elements have, and can selectively unset $this->data['objectName'] or $this->data['objectName']['memberName'].